# Setting breakpoints on final methods for subclasses

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints, eclipse-jdt

Is there any way to set a breakpoint in Eclipse JDT on a final method in a superclass that is only triggered, when the method gets invoked on a specific subclass?

For example I'd like to have a breakpoint on `MyClass#notify()` that gets triggered as soon as any thread invokes

```
MyClass test...
synchronized (test) {
    test.notify();
}
```

But the breakpoint should only be triggered for instances of `MyClass` and not for any `Object`.

Is there perhaps a way to filter breakpoints on `Object#notify()` e.g. by using a [conditional breakpoint](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-condition_option.htm)? I already tried conditions like `this instanceof somepackage.TestNotifyBreakpoint.MyClass` and `this.getClass().getName().equals("somepackage.TestNotifyBreakpoint.MyClass")` but with no luck: the first condition gives me a `somepackage cannot be resolved to a type` error and the second condition an `Attempt to send a message to a non object value` error.

---

Here is a simple example - the breakpoint should trigger when `test.notify();` gets executed.

```
package somepackage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestNotifyBreakpoint {
    public static class MyClass {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass test = new MyClass();
        Thread t = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("waiting for notify");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                synchronized (test) {
                    System.out.println("About to notify");
                    test.notify(); // should trigger the brakepoint
                }
                System.out.println("Notify done");
            }
        };
        t.start();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the conditonal breakpoint `test instanceof somepackage.MyObject` at the line `// should trigger the brakepoint`?

Comment: `class MyObject` or `class MyClass`? And you don't override the `notify` method in `MyClass`/`MyObject`? Where do you set the breakpoint?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and I get the error "somepackage.MyObject cannot be resolved to a type" - I believe because the expression only gets executed in the scope of `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: @Thomas I added the example just for convenience after asking the question - it doesn't really matter if it is `MyClass` or `MyObject`. The breakpoint gets set on `java.lang.Object#notify()`.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, because notify is a native method and you cannot access `this` in its scope (I tried but JDT errors out, perhaps that can be fixed). I would wrap notify on your class, call that when available and set the breakpoint in a wrapper. Alternatively you could use AspectJ to instrument all call sites of `notify()` and set a breakpoint in the advice. That will work for third party code.